# Asyncify string joining in Python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have the following code snippet which I want to transform into asynchronous code (`data` tends to be a large Iterable):

```py
transformed_data = (do_some_transformation(d) for d in data)
stacked_jsons = "\n\n".join(json.dumps(t, separators=(",", ":")) for t in transformed_data)
```

I managed to rewrite the `do_some_transformation`-function to be async so I can do the following:

```py
transformed_data = (await do_some_transformation(d) for d in data)
async_generator = (json.dumps(event, separators=(",", ":")) async for t in transformed_data)
stacked_jsons = ???
```

What's the best way to incrementally join the jsons produced by the async generator so that the joining process is also asynchronous?
This snippet is part of a larger I/O-bound-application which and has many asynchronous components and thus would profit from asynchifying everything.

Comment: Do you actually need the entire ``stacked_jsons`` in-memory, or are you going to send them along – to a file, over a socket, or similar – anyway?

Comment: "Would that even make sense?" This strongly depends on what you are actually doing. ``str``-joining itself is very fast but is inherently a synchronous operation; all you can do is regularly yield (e.g. after each item) to allow other tasks to run. Of course, ``async`` itself only brings an advantage if you actually have any other proper async tasks to begin with.

Comment: asyncio will speedup when you have to wait a lot (networking, fileio, userinput, ...). From what i can see in this usecase, asyncio isn't really usefull since these tasks are cpu bound. If you really want to speed things up see multiprocessing, but that has a whole set of challenges by itself.
[processpools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) might be usefull

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @MisterMiyagi Yes i need them in memory because I have to POST them in bulk to an API which doesn't support streaming. So if I get that right it al comes down to wether `do_some_transformation` is worth asynchifing and I can leave the rest as is? Im not sure that processpools would justify that, im talking about 10k dicts with about 20-40 keys at absolute maximum.

Comment: Okey I made too much assumptions and provided too little context, I'm sorry. This snippet is part of a REST-Client which can be executed in a "regular" event loop (started manually by asyncio.run()) AND (predominantly) in a bigger FastAPI application where it has to share the eventloop with other async components. So this standalone snippet does not make much sense if you don't know in which context it's executed. I'm aware that there's no performance gain from restructuring this code by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `str.join` is to transform an entire list *at once*.<sup>1</sup> If items arrive incrementally, it can be advantageous to accumulate them one by one.

```py
async def join(by: str, _items: 'AsyncIterable[str]') -> str:
    """Asynchronously joins items with some string"""
    result = ""
    async for item in _items:
        if result and by:  # only add the separator between items
            result += by
        result += item
    return result
```

The `async for` loop is sufficient to let the async iterable suspend between items so that other tasks may run. The primary advantage of this approach is that even for very many items, this never stalls the event loop for longer than adding the next item.

This utility can directly digest the async generator:

```
stacked_jsons = join("\n\n", (json.dumps(event, separators=(",", ":")) async for t in transformed_data))
```

---

When it is know that the data is small enough that `str.join` runs in adequate time, one can directly convert the data to a `list` instead and use `str.join`:

```
stacked_jsons = "\n\n".join([json.dumps(event, separators=(",", ":")) async for t in transformed_data])
```

The `[... async for ...]` construct is an [*asynchronous* list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries). This *internally* works asynchronously to iterate, but produces a regular `list` once all items are fetched – only this resulting `list` is passed to `str.join` and can be processed synchronously.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even when joining an iterable, `str.join` will internally turn it into a `list` first.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I think that the async for comprehension is just what i need for now because the produced string will be mostly only a couple of hundred kilobytes big so it should run in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

More in depth explanation about my comment:

Asyncio is a great tool if your processor has a lot of waiting to do.
For example: when you make request to a db over the network, after the request is sent your cpu just does nothing until it gets an answer.

Using the async await syntax you can have your processor execute other tasks while "waiting" for the current one to finish. this does not mean it runs them in parallel. There is only one task running at a time.

In your case (for what i can see) the cpu never waits for something it is constantly running string operations.

if you want to run these operations in parallel you might want to take a look at [ProcesPools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).
This is not bound by a single process and core but will spread the processing over several cores to run it in parallel.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        transformed_data = executor.map(do_some_transformation, data) #returns an iterable

    stacked_jsons = "\n\n".join(json.dumps(t, separators=(",", ":")) for t in transformed_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope the provided code can help you.

ps.
The if `__name__` part is required

edit: i saw your comment about 10k dicts, assume you have 8 cores (ignore multithreading) then each process will only transform 1250 dicts, instead of the 10k your main thread does now. These processes run simultaniously and although the performance increase is not linear it should process them a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation. As is commented at my initial question I gave you too little information to work with. Only by looking at the stuff i provided this is the best solution i guess.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Consider using producer/consumer pattern, if `do_some_transformation` is IO bound, and you **really** want an incremental aggregation.

> Of course, async itself only brings an advantage if you actually have any other proper async tasks to begin with.

As @MisterMiyagi said, if `do_some_transformation` is IO bound and time consuming, firing all transformation as a horde of async tasks can be a good idea.

Example code:

```py
import asyncio
import json


data = ({"large": "data"},) * 3  # large
stacked_jsons = ""


async def transform(d: dict, q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    # `do_some_transformation`: long IO bound task
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await q.put(d)


# WARNING: incremental concatination of string would be slow,
# since string is immutable.
async def join(q: asyncio.Queue):
    global stacked_jsons
    while True:
        d = await q.get()
        stacked_jsons += json.dumps(d, separators=(",", ":")) + "\n\n"
        q.task_done()


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    producers = [asyncio.create_task(transform(d, q)) for d in data]
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(join(q))
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    await q.join()  # Implicitly awaits consumers, too
    consumer.cancel()
    print(stacked_jsons)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

So that `do_some_transformation` don't block each other. Output:

```sh
$ python test.py
{"large":"data"}
{"large":"data"}
{"large":"data"}

test.py executed in 1.00 seconds.
```

Besides, I don't think incremental concatenation of string is a good idea, since string is immutable and a lot of memory would be wasted ;)

Reference: [Async IO in Python: A Complete Walkthrough - Real Python](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)